# Nginx Keep Alive

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver, keep-alive

How do I set the Keep Alive in Nginx? Do I need to install some module? If so, how?

I have enabled it in Apache but the Headers are still showing it as closed Connection.

I am on Centos 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it can be done via HTTPCOREMODULE ( http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html )

look if this is set: keepalive_disable, if so delete it.